# Remove the "Region & Language Settings" option from GNOME Onscreen Keyboard

Tags: 20.04, onscreen-keyboard

I use Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to install a kiosk and I need to hide/remove the *Region & Language Settings* option from the GNOME Onscreen Keyboard (GOK) when I press the flag key.

[image: GNOME Onscreen Keyboard showing the flag menu]

As you can see in the attached picture, when I press the flag key, a menu opens that allows to choose the keyboard I want to use (i.e. English (US) or anything else I have installed).

The other option there, the one that bothers me, is that I am able to enter the *Region & Language Settings*, which opens Settings → *Region & Language Settings*. So a user has the option to change all parameters inside  Settings (add/remove Keyboards, change network, keyboard shortcuts, display, users, screen saver, etc.), which obviously I don't want for the kiosk.

Is there a way to remove the *Region & Language Settings* option from GNOME Onscreen Keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve the goal, by denying the user to open the “Region & Language settings”.

When the user chooses the “Region & Language settings” option, nothing happens.

In order to complete this task,

a)  From a sudo user, create a group (i.e. “sysadmins”) and add the admins' users inside (the users who wants to access the settings)

`sudo addgroup sysadmins`

`sudo adduser AdminUser1 sysadmins`

`sudo adduser root sysadmins`

b) Change the owner of the “gnome-control-center” to the above group “sysadmins”

`sudo chown root:sysadmins /usr/bin/gnome-control-center`

c) Change permissions to the above file, so only member from the above group can execute the Settings

`sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/gnome-control-center`

d)  Logout, login and we are ready!